# In R save input names within function as a comment

Tags: r

I would like to save the inputs/commands within a function as a comment in the end of the function. Please see example below.

```
Name1 <- c(1, 2, 3)
Name2 <- c(4, 5, 6)

addition <- function(x, y){
  z <- x + y
  comment(z) <- paste(x, y)
  z
}
z <- addition(x=Name1, y=Name2)
comment(z)
```

I would like the output of `comment(z)` to be `Name1  Name2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the comment as a "comment" attribute.

R already has the following functions for "comment" attributes but you could define them yourself, e.g., if you want to name the attribute differently. The advantage of the inbuilt "comment" attribute is that `print` doesn't print it. The disadvantage is that its content is restricted to text.

```
##assignment function
#"comment<-" <- function(x, value) {
#  attr(x, "comment") <- value
#  x
#}
#
##accessor function    
#comment <- function(x) attr(x, "comment")
```

You then need to substitute the arguments into `paste`:

```
addition <- function(x, y){
  z <- x + y
  comment(z) <- paste(substitute(x), substitute(y))
  z
}
z <- addition(x=Name1, y=Name2)
comment(z)
#[1] "Name1 Name2"
```

Personally, I'd prefer `comment(z) <- deparse(match.call())`.